# WP-Admin throws 404 after changing wp-config Salts

Tags: wp-admin, wp-config

I was looking around my site's files to see, where an old version of jQuery is defined.
Somewhat found the culprit, but also changed salts.

After changing salts, the WP-Admin zone throws 404 now.

Comment: Changing the salts will invalidate all user passwords, all sessions, all cache keys, your salts/secrets are a part of all the password hashes. You should not have changed them. You will need to reset all your passwords. Also, embed your screenshots in the question instead of using an external service

Comment: Also, have you verified those files actually exist? What's your question? You need to be able to ask a clear question that someone can answer using facts that gets marked as the solution for all users with that question